# Возникает синий экран каждые 15 минут

Tags: windows, windows-10

Каждые 15 минут возникает синий экран и выдаёт такие ошибки IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL либо
IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL, файл netio.sys
Либо
KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE
Начало это происходить после того как поменял термопасту 
Помогите устранить проблему

Comment: температурку проверь, до появления синего

Comment: @АлексДанилин только поменял термопасту , он не успевает нагреваться даже до появления

Comment: Проц из сокета вынимал?

Comment: @donRumata , да , вынимал

Comment: 1. Зачем? 2. Скорее всего ты погнул ножки или запачкал их термопастой.

Comment: @donRumata , что бы нормально снять предыдущий слой термопасты, они ровные и чистые , я проверял

Comment: Чтобы снять прошлый слой - нужна сухая салфетка и терпение. Проверь ещё раз и если есть увеличительное стекло - посмотри через него. И под хорошим светом.

Comment: @donRumata , я еще ресетил биос , могло это случится из за этого?

Comment: В теории - да, на практике - на дефолтных настройках всё должно работать в штатном режиме. Попробуй обновить на новую версию.